# I have an html button I'm trying to redirect to a PHP file in XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

I have a button in my html form that I want it to take user to food.php when they click on it, I did this but it's not redirecting, Please help

`<a href="food.php">
<button name="submit" type="button" id="food">Food - Equipment</button> 
</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<a href="food.php" id="food"><button>Food - Equipment</button></a>
```

Comment: or do I need to specify the directory ? even though they in the same folder ?

Comment: Is the button inside your form? eg. `<form> <button> </form>`

Comment: And are you trying to submit the form or redirect without submitting?

Comment: So I created a form to checkout items, first is checkout.php and second is checkin.php but I want user to be able to select either option from index.php it's just two button on the index.php homepage, and when they click either, they will be redirect.

Comment: Thanks man, apparently I was trying to use a submit button as a normal button to redirect

Answer (score 0):

Why use a button element inside a link tag? Why not just:

```
<a href="food.php" id="food">Food - Equipment</a>
```

Try that and see if it fixes it.

Comment: I wanted it to be a button and not just ordinary link

Comment: This worked but I only resulted in an underlined link and I wanted to return the CSS of the button.

Comment: Take a look at this, see if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-do-i-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link

Answer (score 0):

A button is requested, not a link.  Sometimes linked php files don't work as expected in some browsers. Use a form submit button and you'll get what you're looking for.

```
<form action="food.php" method="GET"> <!-- use get or post if you want
                                        to send anything -->
<input type="submit" value="GO">
</form>
```